# Jquery Out of memory error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I want to blink a div in my form continuously, while this div is blinking I should be able to do anything in my form (in other divs).
I am blinking div using

```
 function blinking(div) {
        timer = setInterval(blink, 2000);
        function blink() {
            div.fadeOut(800, function () {
                div.fadeIn(800);
            });

            $("#dvTbCallbackTitle").fadeOut(800, function () {
                $("#dvTbCallbackTitle").fadeIn(800);
            });
        }


    }
```

However after 5-10 minutes this gives me "System out of memeory exception" error: at line  :

```
return this.animate( props, speed, easing, callback );
```

What could be cause of this error? And how to fix it?

Comment: Show us your full code, i can't see `return this.animate( props, speed, easing, callback );` in your code

Comment: @shadow the fadeIn will be using it

Comment: @shadow this line is my jquery-1.10.2.js file.

Comment: @user1181942 And how you are calling it ?

Comment: @shadow FadeIn function internally calls it.

Comment: @user1181942 I mean to say how to you called blinking() ?